# when first if statement true continue with next if statement

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements, control-flow

python 3.8.11

I want to call the function num_okay in another file. and I want to return the specific "solu" for each number if the if statement is true.

rn it's only returning the first if statement. but I want it to return all the if statements that are correct, not only the first time

and if the first if statement is false I want to continue running the next if statement

thankss

```
numberA=1

numberB=2

numberC=3

numberD=4

def num_okay():

    if numberA < 20 or numberA > 30:
        solu= 'numberA is okay'
        return solu

    if numberB < 20 or numberB > 30:
        solu = 'numberB is okay'
        return solu

    if numberC < 20 or numberC > 30:
        solu = 'numberC is okay'
        return solu

    if numberD < 20 or numberD > 30:
        solu = 'numberD is okay'
        return solu

    else:
        return "NO number is okay"
```

Comment: Save the 4 different values of `solu` in a list instead of returning straightaway. Only return the list *after* all 4 tests have run.

Comment: Concatenate the "succeded" ones and return that. You can't return multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
numberA=1

numberB=2

numberC=3

numberD=4

def num_okay():
    solu=""
    if numberA < 20 or numberA > 30:
        solu= 'numberA is okay'
    

    if numberB < 20 or numberB > 30:
        solu = solu+' numberB is okay'
    

    if numberC < 20 or numberC > 30:
        solu = solu+' numberC is okay'
    

    if numberD < 20 or numberD > 30:
        solu = solu+' numberD is okay'
    

    else:
        return "NO number is okay"
    
    
    return solu
    
print(num_okay())
```

It's not that it is not entering other if statements you return  it in 1st if so it doesn't go to the rest here I have simply concated the string so it give 1 string with all the data from if statements hope this does what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd like this result, but sure, if you like it, I think you should use the following code, since it doesn't use that many if... statements:

```
i = 0
numbers = [
  ["numberA", 19],
  ["numberB", 27],
  ["numberC", 83],
  ["numberD", 23]
]

def num_okay():
  global i
  while i != 4:
    if numbers[i][1] < 20 or numbers[i][1] > 30:
      print(numbers[i][0] + " is okay")
    else:
      print(numbers[i][0] + " is not okay")
    i += 1

num_okay()
```

**The output would be:**

numberA is okay

numberB is not okay

numberC is okay

numberD is not okay

If you don't really understand the code, feel free to ask me, because I'd be more than happy to explain!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all statements that are `True`, you could do the following:

```py
numberA=1
numberB=2
numberC=3
numberD=4

result = []

def num_okay():
    if numberA < 20 or numberA > 30:
        solu= 'numberA is okay'
        result.append(solu)

    if numberB < 20 or numberB > 30:
        solu = 'numberB is okay'
        result.append(solu)

    if numberC < 20 or numberC > 30:
        solu = 'numberC is okay'
        result.append(solu)

    if numberD < 20 or numberD > 30:
        solu = 'numberD is okay'
        result.append(solu)

    else:
        result.append("NO number is okay")
    return result

print(num_okay())
```

The above code return list of all matching statements. You could later convert it as per the use-case.